# android application, when i try to exit from immersive mode to normal, a white bar show on the top of toolbar, what i can do to this?

Tags: android, kotlin

immersive flag:

```kotlin
const val FLAGS_FULLSCREEN =
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

I clear all flags when  exit immersive mode

```kotlin
binding.root.post {
            binding.root.systemUiVisibility =View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
        }
```

i set immersive mode in onResume(), and exit in onPause()

https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Hb743b7662ef14e119ed049bea49ba234G.jpg

Comment: Please elaborate a little more, include images and document the code. Apart from that, take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/gesturenav

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: my reputation is too low to add a image,but i add a link to that.does this is clear?